# How to consistently organize code for debugging?

Tags: debugging, logging, oop, coding-style

When working in a big project that requires debugging (like every project) you realize how much people love "printf" before the IDE's built-in debugger. By this I mean

- Sometimes you need to render variable values to screen (specially for interactive debugging).
- Sometimes to log them in a file
- Sometimes you have to change the visibility (make them public) just to another class to access it (a logger or a renderer for example).
- Some other times you need to save the previous value in a member just to contrast it with the new during debugging
- ...

When a project gets huge with a lot of people working on it, all this debugging-specific code can get messy and hard to differentiate from normal code. This can be crazy for those who have to update/change someone else's code or to prepare it for a release.

How do you solve this?

It is always good to have naming standards and I guess that *debug-coding standards* should be quite useful (like marking every debug-variable with a _DBG sufix). But I also guess naming is just not enough. Maybe centralizing it into a friendly tracker class, or creating a robust base of macros in order to erase it all for the release. I don't know.

*What design techniques, patterns and standards would you embrace if you are asked to write a debug-coding document for all others in the project to follow?*

I am not talking about tools, libraries or IDE-specific commands, but for OO design decisions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't commit debugging code, just debuggin tools.

Loggin OTOH has a natural place in execption handling routines and such. Also a few well placed logging statments in a few commonly used APIs can be good for debugging.

Like one log statment to log all SQL executed from the system.

Answer (score 0):

My vote would be with what you described as a friendly tracker class.  This class would keep all of that centralized, and potentially even allow you to change debug/logging strategies dynamically.

I would avoid things like Macros simply because that's a compiler trick, and not true OO.  By abstracting the concept of debug/logging, you have the opportunity to do lots of things with it including making it a no-op if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Logging or debugging?  I believe that well-designed and properly unit-tested application should not need to be permanently instrumented for debugging.  Logging on the other hand can be very useful, both in finding bugs and auditing program actions.  Rather than cover a lot of information that you can get elsewhere, I would point you at [logging.apache.org](http://logging.apache.org) for either concrete implementations that you can use or a template for a reasonable design of a logging infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's particularly important to avoid using System.outs / printfs directly and instead use (even a custom) logging class. That at least gives you a centralized kill-switch for all the loggings (minus the call costs in Java).

It is also useful to have that log class have info/warn/error/caveat, etc.

I would be careful about error levels, user ids, metadata, etc. since people don't always add them.

Also, one of the most common problems that I've seen is that people put temporary printfs in the code as they debug something, and then forget where they put them. I use a tool that tracks everything that I do so I can quickly identify all my recent edits since an abstract checkpoint and delete them. In most cases, however, you may want to pose special rules on debug code that can be checked into your source control.

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 you've got

```
Debug.Print
```

which sends output to a window in the IDE. It's bearable for small projects. VB6 also has

```
#If <some var set in the project properties>
'debugging code
#End If
```

I have a logging class which I declare at the top with

```
Dim Trc as Std.Traces
```

and use in various places (often inside #If/#End If blocks)

```
Trc.Tracing = True
Trc.Tracefile = "c:\temp\app.log"
Trc.Trace 'with no argument stores date stamp
Trc.Trace "Var=" & var
```

Yes it does get messy, and yes I wish there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

We routinely are beginning to use a static class that we write trace messages to.  It is very basic and still requires a call from the executing method, but it serves our purpose.

In the .NET world, there is already a fair amount of built in trace information available, so we do not need to worry about which methods are called or what the execution time is.  These are more for specific events which occur in the execution of the code.

If your language does not support, through its tracing constructs, categorization of messages, it should be something that you add to your tracing code.  Something to the effect that will identify different levels of importance and/or functional areas is a great start.

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid instrumenting your code by modifying it. Learn to use a debugger. Make logging and error handling easy. Have a look at [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 0):

Debugging/Logging code can indeed be intrusive.   In our C++ projects, we wrap common debug/log code in macros - very much like asserts.  I often find that logging is most usefull in the lower level components so it doesn't have to go everywhere.

There is a lot in the other answers to both agree and disagree with :)   Having debug/logging code can be a very valuable tool for troubleshooting problems.  In Windows, there are many techniques - the two major ones are:

- Extensive use of checked (DBG) build asserts *and* lots of testing on DBG builds.
- the use of ETW in what we call 'fre' or 'retail' builds.

Checked builds (what most ohter call DEBUG builds) are very helpfull for us as well.  We run all our tests on both 'fre' and 'chk' builds (on x86 and AMD64 as well, all serever stuff runs on Itanium too...).  Some people even self host (dogfood) on checked builds.   This does two things

1. Finds lots of bugs that woldn't be found otherwise.
2. Quickly elimintes noisy or unnessary asserts.

In Windows, we use [Event Tracing for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968803.aspx) (ETW) extensively.   ETW is an efficient static logging mechanism.  The NT kernel and many components are very well instrumented.   ETW has a lot of advantages:

- Any ETW event provider can be dynamically enabled/disabled at run time - no rebooting or process restarts required.  Most ETW providers provide granular control over individual events, or groups of events.
- Events from any provider (most importantly the kernel) can be merged into a single trace so all events can be correlated.
- A merged trace can be copied off the box and fully processed - with symbols.
- The NT kernel sample pofile interrupt can generate an ETW event - this yeilds a very light weight sample profiler that can be used *any time*
- On Vista and Windows Server 2008, logging an event is lock free and fully multi-core aware - a thread on each processor can independently log events with no synchronization needed between them.

This is hugly valuable for us, and can be for your Windows code as well - ETW is usuable by any component - including user mode, drivers and other kernel components.

One thing we often do is write a streaming ETW consumer.  Instead of putting printfs in the code, I just put ETW events at intersting places.   When my componetn is running, I can then just run my ETW watcher at any time - the watcher receivs the events and displays them, conts them, or does other interesting things with them.

I very much respectfully disagree with tvanfosson.  Even the best code can benefit from well implemented logging.  Well implimented static run-time logging can make finding many problems straight forward - without it, you have zero visiblilty into what is happening in your component.  You can look at inputs, outputs and guess -that's about it.

They key here is the term 'well implimented'.  Instrumentation must be in the right place.  Like any thing else, this requries some thought and planning. If it is not in helpfull/intersting places, then it will not help you find problems in a a development, testing, or deployed scenario.  You can also have too much instrumeation causing perf problems when it is on - or even off!

Of course, different software products or componetns will have different needs.  Some things may need very little instrumenation.  But a widely depolyed or critical component can greatly benefit from weill egineered instrumeantion.

Here is a scenario for you (note, this very well may not apply to you...:) ).  Lets say you have a line-of-business app deployed on every desktop in your company - hundreds or thousands of users.   What do you do when someone has a pbolem?   Do yo stop by their office and hookup a debugger?  If so, how do you know what version they have?  Where do you get the right symbols?  How do you get the debuger on their system?  What if it only happens once every few hours or days?  Are you going to let the system run with the debugger connected all that time?

As you can imagine - hooking up debugger in this scenario is disruptive.

If your component is instrumented with ETW, then you could ask your user to simply turn on tracing; continue to do his/her work; then hit the "WTF" button when the problem happens.   Even better: your app may have be able to self log - detecting problems at run time and turning on logging auto-magicaly.   It could even send you ETW files when problems occured.

These are just simple exmples - logging can be handled many different ways.  My key recomendation here is to think about how loging might be able to help you find, debug, and fix problems in your componetns at dev time, test time, and after they are deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I was burnt by the same issue in about every project I've been involved with, so now I have this habit that involves extensive use of logging libraries (whatever the language/platform provides) from the start. Any [Log4X port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4J) is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Building yourself some proper debug tools can be extremely valuable.  For example in a 3D environment, you might have an option to display the octree, or to render planned AI paths, or to draw waypoints that are normally invisible.  You'd probably also want some on-screen display to aid with profiling too: the current framerate, count of polygons on screen, texture memory usage, and so on.

Although this takes some time and effort to do, in the long run it can save you a lot of time and frustration.